# How can you filter PDF files with finfo() for upload?

Tags: php

I am having an issue with finfo and am not sure what step I am missing.

Also, on a side note, the

> $message = $upload_errors[$error];

won't actually display errors if I put the wrong upload directory to test it out.   Everything else works fine.

This is a multiple input file upload from a form:

```
if(isset($_FILES['myFile'])){
$name_array = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['myFile']['error'];

        $upload_dir = "uploads/";

        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){

            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp_name_array[$i]);
            $ok = false;
            switch ($mime) {
               case 'application/pdf'
                    $mimeok = true;
               default:
                   die("Unknown/not permitted file type");
            }

            // 1 megabyte is 1,048,576 bytes. 5 megabyte limit 5242880
            if ($size_array[$i] > 5242880) {
                echo "Error: Document size exceeds maximum limit of 5 MB.  Please reduce the file size and retry upload";
            }else{
                if ($mimeok = false) {  
                                echo "Not correct file type<br>";
                } else{

                    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], $upload_dir.$name_array[$i])){
                        echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";

                    } else {

                    $error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];
                    $message = $upload_errors[$error];
                    echo $message;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you are initializing `$ok` but for the rest of the script you are using `$mimeok`

but the main problem is because you are doing an assignment instead of a check in your if:

```
if ($mimeok = false)
            ^ should be == or even ===
```

Comment: I feel dumb. Duh..  Just missed that.  The php errors out, so there must be something else.  It is only the finfo part that causes the error

Comment: It is one of these 2 lines: $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp_name_array[$i]);

Comment: `$error = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'];` should be `$error = $error_array[$i]`

Comment: That fixed the errors!  I am not sure why finfo_open isn't working? I am using php 5.5

Comment: what's "not working"? what does `$mime` contain? does it produce errors?

Comment: I must not have PECL installed for some reason on my xampp localhost.  That's what I have discovered about finfo.